# .load() in jQuery and odd behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm implementing a simple jQuery script on a website that loads content from one section of a webpage into the 'display container' on the same webpage.

The content i'm loading is multiple div's which are all wrapped in an outer `<div>` which has been hidden from view.

I have the `display container div` and several links the use can click on. Each time they click a link, the appropriate matched content is loaded in to the display container.

My jQuery.

---

```
$(".Prod-Link-2").click(function(e){

e.preventDefault();
$("#ITARGET").empty();
$("#ITARGET").prepend('<img id="theImg" src="http://sensing-precision.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/page-loader.gif" />');

$("#ITARGET").load($(this).attr('href'));

});
```

Menu HTML

---

```
<div class="MPD">
<div class="Option">
<a class="Prod-Link-2" id ="DEF" href ="/electricalelectronic-products/alf150 #specTable" ><p>SPECIFICATIONS</p></a>
</div>
<div class="Option">
<a class="Prod-Link-2" href ="/electricalelectronic-products/alf150 #COMPARE" ><p>ALF150 v ALF150+</p></a>
</div>
<div class="Option">
<a class="Prod-Link-2" href ="/electricalelectronic-products/alf150 #FEAT" ><p>APPLICATIONS</p></a>
</div>
<div class="Option">
<a class="Prod-Link-2" href ="/electricalelectronic-products/alf150 #ACCESSORY" ><p>ACCESSORIES</p></a>
</div>
</div>
```

The Target div

---

```
<div class="Info-Target" id="ITARGET">

</div>
```

So my problem is this all works except one of the links.

My hidden div has 4 content divs and 2 tables inside which all have their own IDs. `SPECIFICATIONS` grabs the `#specTable`, `APPLICATIONS` grabs the `#FEAT` div etc etc.. `ACCESSORIES` will not load the `#ACCESSORY` div at all and I don't know why. The script initializes and the page loader gif is displayed, but then instead of displaying the content I'm trying to load.. it displays nothing.

The hidden area format

---

```
<div style="display: none;">

<div id ="COMPARE"> some content </div>
<table id="specTable"> some content </div>
<div id ="ACCESSORY"> some content </div>

etc ....

</div>
```

For test purposes

---

```
<div id="ACCESSORY">
<p> This is the accessory div </p>
</div>
```

No matter what I change the name to in the ID tag and the links `href attr`, it will not load (I even tried making a new div with a different name and moving the div up to top of the hidden content area thinking it was maybe a loading issue), but if I change the links `href attr` to one of the tables or a different div such as `#FEAT` or `#specTable`.. it loads that fine.

My gut feeling is that there is some qwirk with `jQuery` and `.load()` that i'm unaware of.

Comment: `<table id="specTable"> some content </div>` — Try https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Comment: ah, that closing div should be </table> which it is in my code. That's a typo I made when typing the question.

Comment: The problem is that [the page you're loading](http://sensing-precision.com/electricalelectronic-products/alf150/) doesn't have an HTML-element with ID `ACCESSORY`. `FEAT`, `specTable` and `COMPARE`exist but not `ACCESSORY`.

Comment: Sani... thank you! Although Im doing this in Development mode, the script was looking through the actual Live page!!!!

Answer (score 1):

This problem may be CSS related.  I've just taken a look at a couple of products, and wherever the content includes lists, the display appears blank because of extremely excessive white-space.

This CSS rule seems to be the culprit:

```
.Features li:before  { content: url(#)!important; }
```